# Open nodes from menu in ajax mode

Tags: ajax, routes

I have a custom module that shows node in ajax mode with `hook_menu()` .
how can i show nodes from menu in ajax mode .
here is my code :

```
    <?php

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function sample_ajax_menu() {
  $items['sample-ajax/page'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'sample_ajax_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['sample-ajax/nojs/%node'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'sample_ajax_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1, 2),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['sample-ajax/ajax/%node'] = array(
    'delivery callback' => 'ajax_deliver',
    ) + $items['sample-ajax/nojs/%node'];

  return $items;
}

function sample_ajax_page() {
  drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.ajax');
  return array(
    '#markup' => l(t('Click here'), 'sample-ajax/nojs/1', array('attributes' => array('class' => array('use-ajax')))),
  );
}

function sample_ajax_callback($ajax, $node) {
  $is_ajax = $ajax === 'ajax';

  if ($is_ajax) {
    $commands = array();
    $node_view = node_view($node);
    $commands[] = ajax_command_html('#block-system-powered-by div.content', drupal_render($node_view));
    return array(
      '#type' => 'ajax',
      '#commands' => $commands,
    );
  } else {
    return node_view($node);
  }
}
```

when i add use-ajax class to links in main-menu i get error
***Upadte***
[image: Error]

any idea ??

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error you are getting into your question?

Comment: Ok , i upadated my question . please see it

Comment: I have checked you code, its working fine for me after some changes. Can you check your browser console before AJAX call.

Comment: did you test it from main menu ? @inizo